# Problema con una agrupación por minutos

Tags: mysql, sql

Ej. si se empieza a las 16:26 y la agrupación es por 5 minutos enseguida me muestra 16:30 y de ahí 16:35, 16:40, etc.

Con 10 minutos pasa algo similar, pero se regresa a las 16:20 y luego ya muestra 16:30, 16:40 etc .. Y quiero saber cómo puedo solucionar esto.

Esta es mi consulta:

Comment: ¿Que estructura tiene la tabla mvs?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `mvs` (
  `id_value` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identificador` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_mvs` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_remote` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hours` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_paciente` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_value`),
  KEY `FK_mvs` (`id_paciente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=175212 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @mary puedes añadir la estructura en la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Ya la agregue, mucas  gracias por la sugerencia :3

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tu query está correcta, siempre que lo que pretendas es agrupar por registros que se encuentren dentro de un rango de tiempo.

En la select que realizas no estás usando la agregación o el grupo creado por el "**group by**". Agrupas de 5 en 5 minutos por hora, pero luego seleccionas el campo **hours** en:

```
select value_mvs,hours
```

Sin embargo no existe un único valor seleccionado para hours, pues los has agrupado de 5 en 5, por lo tanto te podrá el valor que MySql considere, seguramente el primero insertado dentro de ese rango de 5.

Para asegurarte que funciona deberías seleccionar el primero y el último de la agrupación asi:

```
SELECT value_mvs,concat(MIN(hours) ,"-", MAX(hours))
FROM mvs 
WHERE id_paciente = 'exp'
GROUP BY ((60 / 1) ) * HOUR (hours) + FLOOR (MINUTE (hours) /5);
```

Si además quieres tener la hora del inicio del rango real, podrías incluir esto:

```
SELECT value_mvs,concat(MIN(hours) ,"-", MAX(hours)), concat(HOUR (hours),":",(MINUTE (hours)) - (MINUTE (hours) % 5)) as inicial
FROM mvs 
WHERE id_paciente = 'exp'
GROUP BY ((60 / 5) ) * HOUR (hours) + FLOOR (MINUTE (hours) /5);
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que con respecto a las opciones de un combo se deben mostrar los resultados .... si elijo el numero 1 se deben mostrar los resultados por minuto, y así sucesivamente con 2, 5, 10 y 15 ... Es ahi donde esta mi problema ya que a partir del 5 toma otra hora que no es la inicial como tal

Comment: No se si te entiendo bien. Si quiere mostrar todos los registros por intervalo de tiempo tal vez no puedas usar el group by, ya que este solo agrega resultados para operar con ellos, usando MAX, MIN, COUNT, SUM... Pero no te dará todos los resultados agrupados por rango de horas. ¿No deberías usar la condición del where para eso?. En cualquier caso actualizo mi respuesta para que además de darte el rango de horas encontrado en los registros te de la hora "inicial" del rango.

Comment: loq ue deseo es que funcione como se ve en la imagen

Comment: Pues entonces todos los valores que pinta en las columnas deben ser una cálculo basado en la agrupación, una media o un sumatorio o algo parecido. Si pones de intervalo 10 minutos, hay muchos registros que estén dentro de ese intervalo. ¿Cual eliges para mostrar? Creo que lo estás haciendo bien, pero te falta usar las funciones de agregación en la query (SUM, MAX, MIN, COUNT...)

Comment: el asunto es que ... No se como hacerlo ... Por eso pedí ayuda :(